# לעלם ולעלמי עלמיא - (kaddish) isn't this redundant?

Tags: tefilla, translation, kaddish, aramaic

The Artscroll interlinear Siddur translates the words לעלם ולעלמי עלמיא - forever and for all eternity.

Don't "forever" and "for eternity" mean the same thing? What is the simple pshat in these words (I am not looking for kabbalistic explanations, which I assume will talk about multiple עולמות)?

Comment: There's clear allusions here to Daniel 2:20 and 7:18

Comment: Wouldn’t the same question be on the words leolam vahed- forever and ever?

Comment: If I recall correctly לעולם by itself can mean until a certain end albeit in the future with an unknown date, while לעולם ועד (or לעלם ועלמי עלמיא) means literally _forever_.

Comment: To add to @ezra's point, לעולם בהם תעבודו does not mean literally forever

Comment: @n.t. That actually has a known end date as well

Comment: @ezra so why do we mention both, let's just say leolmey olmaya?

Comment: @Chatzkel the English "forever and ever" is similarly 'unnecessary' -- maybe the pshat is a stylistic/poetic one.

Comment: The Ibn Yahya has as his explanation, "וינחלוהו עד עמוד העולם הזה ולעולמי עולמים מהעולם הבא"

Comment: The Malbim interprets Daniel 7:18 in a similar fashion to the Ibn Yahya that עָלְמָא is olam hazeh = this temporal world (העולם הכלה ונפסד) and עָלַם עָלְמַיָּא is olam haba = the future permanent world (העולם הנצחי).

The Metzudos there has a different approach and writes that עָלְמָא here = "for a long time" (eg. eved Ivri serving until yovel).  עָלַם עָלְמַיָּא = permanence and would mean "forever" so the pasuk would imply - not merely for a long time but even forever.

Comment: @EraserX if you fashioned that into an answer i'd upvote

Comment: The issue of מן העולם ועד העולם in [Mishna Brachot 9:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berakhot.9.5?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) might be related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*To reformulate my earlier comment into an answer as per the request of @ezra:*

The phrasing of the kaddish here is most likely taken from **דניאל ז:יח** *(as implied above by @Double AA)*

> עַד עָלְמָא, וְעַד עָלַם עָלְמַיָּא

The equivalent in Hebrew would be **עד העולם, ועד עולם העולמים** and in English would be **until the world, and until the world of worlds**.

The following are two different approaches on how to interpret the phrase.

**1)** **יוסף אבן יחיא** *(as noted by @rosends)* and the **מלבי"ם** write that **עָלְמָא** is *olam hazeh* and **עָלַם עָלְמַיָּא** is *olam haba*.

To quote **Ibn Yahya**:

> עד עמוד **העולם הזה** ולעולמי עולמים **מהעולם הבא**

The **Malbim** provides a sharper contrast between the **future permanent world** *(parallel to עָלַם עָלְמַיָּא)* which will follow the **temporal world** *(parallel to עָלְמָא)*:

> עד העולם, ועד **העולם הנצחי** שיבא אחרי **העולם הכלה ונפסד**

**2)** The **מצודת דוד** on that pasuk takes a different approach and writes:

> עד עולם וחזר ופירש עד עלם עלמיא ור״ל **עד עולם ממש** כי לפעמים יאמר **עולם
> על זמן ארוך** כמו (שמות כא:ו) ועבדו לעלם

Meaning that עָלְמָא here is equivalent to **for a long time** (eg. עבד עברי choosing to serve his master until יובל) and that עָלַם עָלְמַיָּא is equivalent to permanence and would mean **forever** so the pasuk would imply: not merely for a long time but even forever.

Comment: shkoyach what a fine answer